# Единая авторизация для 3-х проектов

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Есть 3 веб-проекта. Серверная часть на PHP, интерфейс - HTML/JS. Для данных каждый проект использвует отдельную базу MySQL. И каждый проект использует авторизацию пользователей. Данные о пользователях хранятся так:

1-й проект: - таблица в базе данных Users "user_id","login","md5password"

```
------------------------------
| 1 | admin | alskdjalsdja23das |
| 2 | user | asdasdasqweqwreds32 |
------------------------------
```

2-й проект: - Обычная BASE авторизация Apache - данные пользователей хранятся в файле .htaccess/.htpasswd

3-й проект: - таблица в базе данных Users: "user_id","login","md5password"

```
-----------------------------
| 1 | moderator | aasdf21321a23das |
| 2 | writer | asdasda456225fs32 |
-----------------------------
```

таблица прав для различных Rights: "right_id","description"

```
-----------------------------
| 1 | read |
| 2 | write |
| 3 | delete |
-----------------------------
```

реляционная таблица назначения прав пользователям Users_Rights: "user_id","right_id"

```
-----------------------------
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
-----------------------------
```

Как создать единую авторизацию для всех трех проектов, со своим интерфейсом управления пользователями.

Я думаю во втором проекте применить  mod_auth_mysql для использования MySQL.
А вот дальше непонятно как быть с уникальностью пользователей. Создавать префиксы для таблиц? Вообщем тупик.

Comment: я думаю нужно сделать независимый модуль авторизации

Comment: И как он разрулит с уникальностью users?

Comment: ну вобщем вам ответили развернуто

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для единой авторизации нужен единый профиль. Поэтому должна быть ещё одна таблица, доступная для всех проектов. Может быть даже несколько таблиц. Там будет auth_profiles: токен пользователя и мб какие то данные о нём: логин, пароль. Ещё одна таблица, в которой написана связь этого профиля с ресурсами на которых он будет автоизован. Примерно такая таблица: идентификатор_ресурса, идентификатор пользователя на этом ресурсе. Далее авторизация происходит по логину и паролю из базы общих профилей auth_profiles. Генерируется токен (не на всегда, срок жизни желательно, быть может даже в отдельную таблицу, если нужно сделать возможность нескольких авторизаций одного человека с разных клиентов). И по токену делать авторизацию на других сайтах. При первом заходе если человек не авторизован, если есть у него токен (в куках, сессии) то авторизовать.

А вообще рекомендую посмотреть про oAuth. Сделать по его принципам. По таким принципам работает например вконтакте авторизация.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала - судя по всему вы уже доросли до отдельного модуля авторизации. 
Т.е. при попытке авторизоваться на одном из проектов будет необходимо например перенаправить пользователя на отдельный ресурс который проверит и авторизует пользователя.

Далее - происходит переадресация на ресурс откуда этот пользователь пришел. При этом в тех же куках необходимо хранить значение которое первый ресурс проверит и убедится что пользователь уже авторизован.

А по поводу уникальности - очень советую слить эти три базы пользователей в одну. При этом добавить пометку откуда этот пользователь пришел(с какой базы).

Далее... Пользователь приходит с ресурса один и вводит логин и пароль, вы это видите, модуль видит что пользователь пришел с ресурса 1 и ввел пароль и логин которые соответствуют пользователю который пришел с ресурса 1. После чего он должен авторизовать пользователя и принудительно заставить его сменить логин.

Как это оправдать - думайте уже сами. Можете сообщить пользователю что его логин - это теперь его ник, и он будет виден, а логин ему теперь необходимо придумать по новой что бы другие пользователи его не видели.

Вот как-то так если простыми словами :)

Comment: Спасибо всем за направление. Будем дальше разбиратся